# Problema cuando inicio git status

Tags: git, vscode, terminal

Modifico dos archivos (html y js) y cuando inicio git status para que me muestre que tengo 2 archivos por guardar antes de comitear y pushear, me muestra todas las carpetas que tengo en mi escritorio. En vez de aparecer Carpeta/Subcarpeta/ y luego para escribir comandos, me aparece Users/Usuario/Desktop/Carpeta/Subcarpeta; entonces me muestra todas las carpetas de mi escritorio como si las tuviera que pushear. Es decir, quiero hacer git add . y subir los 2 archivos que modifique, pero si hago git add ., me sube todo mi escritorio basicamente.

Comment: Suena a que hiciste `git init` en el sitio equivocado.. Probablemente lo hiciste directamente sobre tu `home` en vez de hacerlo en el directorio del proyecto.

Comment: Puedes comprobar el directorio raíz de git con `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

Comment: el `.` es carpeta/directorio actual ... `git add .` significa agrega todo lo q esta en esta carpeta y sub carpetas. si estas en el escritorio va a agregar el escritorio y todo lo q encuentre

Comment: Como lo corrijo?

Comment: Si hiciste un `git init` en un sitio inadecuado como tu `home`,  solo ve a ese directorio y borra el subdirectorio `.git` y con eso ya tu `home` no se seguirá viendo cómo un repositorio.