# Problema al iniciar git status

Tags: git, vscode, terminal, repositorio

Modifico dos archivos (html y js) y cuando inicio git status para que me muestre que tengo 2 archivos por guardar antes de comitear y pushear, me muestra todas las carpetas que tengo en mi escritorio. En vez de aparecer Carpeta/Subcarpeta/ y luego para escribir comandos, me aparece Users/Usuario/Desktop/Carpeta/Subcarpeta; entonces me muestra todas las carpetas de mi escritorio como si las tuviera que pushear. Es decir, quiero hacer git add . y subir los 2 archivos que modifique, pero si hago git add ., me sube todo mi escritorio basicamente. Como se corrige?

Comment: Ignacio, esta no es la misma pregunta que publicaste anteriormente?

Comment: @eftshift0 [es verdad.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/610104)

Comment: Ignacio: en lugar de duplicar preguntas, procura colocar un título descriptivo a la pregunta que vas a conservar, y borra la pregunta duplicada. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema cuando inicio git status](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610104/problema-cuando-inicio-git-status)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

como estas? revisa por las dudas que estes parado en la carpeta donde tienes el repo de tu codigo, si tu estabas parado en el escritorio al momento de hacer `git init` y `git add .` te tomara todo en ese directorio como tu repo. asegurate de estar parado en la ruta dentro del repo donde tienes tus archivos, si ya te aparecen como agregados puedes hacer `git reset` y ahi luego si parado dentro de la carpeta correcta hacer `git add .` otra opcion seria agregar individualmente el archivo haciendo `git add /tu/ruta/al/repo/archivo.txt`

Espero te sirva la respuesta,
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya probare con eso!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).